# How to update a custom field while inserting and updating the record using trigger?

Tags: apex, trigger

I have custom object called Opportunity car set object. In the object there are 5 fields.
name, brand, model name(lookup to product),version name (lookup to product),price
Depending upon the selection of model name and version name the price field should be updated. The model name and version name are sent as parameter to get the price value from web service.

**My trigger:**

```
trigger Rfleet_OpptyUpdateC2GPrice on Opportunity_car_set__c (before insert,before update) {

Public String modelOppValue;
Public String versionOppValue;


  for(Opportunity_car_set__c oppcarset:[select id,Price_HT__c,Model__r.Name,Version__r.Name from Opportunity_car_set__c  where id in:trigger.new]){
   system.debug('oppcarset.id----------------->'+oppcarset.id);
   system.debug('oppcarset.Model__r.Name----------------->'+oppcarset.Model__r.Name);
   system.debug('oppcarset.Version__r.Name----------------->'+oppcarset.Version__r.Name);
   modelOppValue = oppcarset.Model__r.Name;
   versionOppValue = oppcarset.Version__r.Name; 
   //Rfleet_DZVersionPrice_CLS.doCallout(modelOppValue,versionOppValue);
   Rfleet_DZVersionPrice_CLS.chkVersionCallOut(modelOppValue,versionOppValue);

      system.debug('modelOppValue--------------------->'+ modelOppValue);
      system.debug('versionOppValue --------------------->'+ versionOppValue);
        }

}
```

**Apex class:**

```
global class Rfleet_DZVersionPrice_CLS {
static String strModelName;
static String strVersionName;
static String strOppid;
@future(callout=true)
public static void chkVersionCallOut(string modelName,string versionName) {
    strModelName = modelName;
    strVersionName = versionName;
    System.debug('strModelName -------------------------------->'+strModelName);
    System.debug('strVersionName -------------------------------->'+strVersionName);
    Rfleet_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS dzVersionPrize = new Rfleet_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS(strModelName,strVersionName);
    ProcessorControl.inFutureContext = true;
    dzVersionPrize.getVersionPrice();
}

}
```

**Webservice class:**

```
public class Rfleet_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS {
public String strJSON {get;set;}
public String strGeturl {get;set;}
public String strGetcountrycode {get;set;}
public String strGetCurrency {get;set;}
public String strModelCode {get;set;}
public String strVersionCode {get;set;}
public String strVersionDocUrl {get;set;}
public String strPriceListURL {get;set;}
public String strOppid {get;set;}
public double strversionPrice{get;set;}
public List<String> lstModelcalOut = new List<String>(); //to get list of model code
public List<String> lstDoCcalOut = new List<String>(); //to get list of docurls
public Map<String,String> mVersion     = new map<String,String>();  //Contains model code+doc url
Rfleet_JSON2ApexC2G_CLS obj = null;
public Rfleet_DZC2GVersionPriceDetails_CLS(String strModelName, String strVersionName) {

    Rfleet_CountryInfo__c cs = Rfleet_CountryInfo__c.getInstance('Algeria');
    strGeturl         =    cs.Rfleet_C2GURL__c;
    strGetcountrycode =    cs.Rfleet_CountryCode__c;
    strGetCurrency    =    cs.Rfleet_Currency__c;
    Opportunity_car_set__c opp=[SELECT Model__r.ProductCode,Version__r.Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c FROM Opportunity_car_set__c where Model__r.name =: strModelName and Version__r.name =:      strVersionName];    
    strModelCode    = opp.Model__r.ProductCode;
    strVersionCode  = opp.Version__r.Rfleet_C2G_version_code__c;
    strOppid        = opp.id;
    system.debug('<<strOppid'+ strOppid);

}

//Common method to Parse the JSON
public String init(String strVersionURL) {
    try {
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest httpReq = new HttpRequest();
        httpReq.setEndpoint(strVersionURL);
        httpReq.setHeader('Accept','application/JSON');
        httpReq.setMethod('GET');
        HttpResponse response = http.send(httpReq);
        strJSON= response.getBody();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        system.debug('<<Method: init Exception ::'+ ex);
    } 
    return  strJSON;     
}

//Used for Getting ModelCode and Doc URL in Map
public Map<String, String> getJSONFromREST() {
    strJSON = init(strGeturl); 
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(strJSON);
    while(parser.nextToken() !=null) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
            String fieldName = parser.getText();
            if(fieldName == 'modelSpecCode') { 
                parser.nextToken();
                lstModelcalOut.add(parser.getText());
            } 
            if(fieldName == 'doc') {
                parser.nextToken();
                lstDoCcalOut.add(parser.getText());
            } 
        }
    }
    for(integer i=0;i<lstModelcalOut.size();i++) {
        mVersion.put(lstModelcalOut.get(i),lstDoCcalOut.get(i));
    }
    system.debug('mVersion===>'+mVersion);
    return mVersion;       
}

//Used to get Version Price URL
public String getVersionPriceURL() {
     Map<string,String> mVersionVal=getJSONFromREST();
    if(mVersionVal.containsKey(strModelCode)) {
        strVersionDocUrl= mVersionVal.get(strModelCode);
    }
    strJSON = init(strVersionDocUrl); 
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(strJSON);
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
            if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) {
                String fieldName = parser.getText();
                if(fieldName == 'pricesList') {
                    parser.nextToken();
                    strPriceListURL=parser.getText();
                    system.debug('strPriceListURL>>>>'+strPriceListURL);
                }
            }    
    }
    return strPriceListURL;         
}
public void getVersionPrice() {
       String strVersionPriceURL=getVersionPriceURL();
       String strJSON = init(strVersionPriceURL);
       obj = Rfleet_JSON2ApexC2G_CLS.parse(strJSON);
       List<Rfleet_JSON2ApexC2G_CLS.PriceList> listPriceList  = obj.PriceList;  
       for(Rfleet_JSON2ApexC2G_CLS.PriceList priceList : listPriceList) {
            String strPriceTypeReference = (String)priceList.priceType.reference;
            List<Rfleet_JSON2ApexC2G_CLS.VersionPriceList>  listVersionPriceList;
            if(strPriceTypeReference =='PVCHT') {
                listVersionPriceList = new List<Rfleet_JSON2ApexC2G_CLS.VersionPriceList>();
                listVersionPriceList = priceList.versionPriceList;
                for(integer i=0; i< listVersionPriceList.size(); i++) {
                    String strversionIdSpecCode = listVersionPriceList.get(i).versionIdSpecCode;
                    if(strversionIdSpecCode==strVersionCode) {
                      strversionPrice = listVersionPriceList.get(i).price;
                      system.debug('<<<<<<<<<VersionId and Price'+ strversionPrice);  
                    }

                }
            } 
        }  
        system.debug('<<<<<<<<<VersionId outside Price'+ strversionPrice);
        Opportunity_car_set__c opp=[SELECT Price_HT__c FROM Opportunity_car_set__c where Model__r.name =:strModelName and Version__r.name =:strVersionName];
        system.debug('opp>>'+ opp);
        opp.Price_HT__c=decimal.Valueof(strversionPrice);
        system.debug('opp next>>'+ opp);
        Update opp;

} 

}
```

*apex class to prevent recursive run:**

```
public class ProcessorControl {  
     public static boolean inFutureContext = false;
}
```

**My problem is:**

While inserting new record price value is not updated.While modifying the record the value is updated after refreshing the page.please help me out!!!thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Since you are using future method(It is an asynchronous process). This will take longer time than synchronous process  check this descussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748175/asynchronous-vs-synchronous-execution-what-does-it-really-mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The webservice call tries to query the record even before its inserted I beleive.

Try changing operation to `after insert` and `after update` in the trigger instead of `before insert` and `before update` respectively

```
trigger Rfleet_OpptyUpdateC2GPrice on Opportunity_car_set__c (after insert,after update) {
    if(system.isFuture()) return;
```

**Update:**

Added check in trigger to avoid recursion

```
if(system.isFuture()) return;
```

Comment: And `after update`, too.

Comment: when I try after insert the price value is retrieved from web service. but it is not updated.It throws error "System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method: Rfleet_DZVersionPrice_CLS.chkVersionCallOut"

Comment: sfdcfox thank you, I updated the answer to reflect the same. @uma see my update,  you need to add if(system.isFuture()) return; to avoid recursion on update from future class

Comment: Hi@karthikselva.Thanks for the update.The value was retrived from weebservice while inserting and updating a record.But after refreshing the page only the value is updated.have to refresh the Page ?Please help me !!

Comment: @uma Yeah since its asynchronous you can't expect the page to reflect immediately,

Comment: @karthickselva:So what is the solution ??How can I overcome this ?

Comment: @uma Try using pollers https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionPoller.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36350/discussion-between-uma-and-karthikselva).